# Why does my test (using pytest) fail and say the database exists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest

I have some unit tests that I am testing using pytest. I want to have the tests create and then destroy an SQLite3 database for each test so that I can test each function with an actual database.

database.py:

```py
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect('geminon.db', check_same_thread=False)
cur = db.cursor()


def create_tables():
    """
    create tables
    """

    cur.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE ships (
    name                TEXT    PRIMARY KEY,
    classification      INTEGER DEFAULT   0,
    number              INTEGER DEFAULT   0,
    damage              INTEGER DEFAULT   0
    )
    """)

def add_ship(name):
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM ships WHERE name=:name LIMIT 1", {'name': name})
    if cur.fetchone() is None:
        cur.execute("insert into ships (name) values (?)", (name,))
        db.commit()
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

test_database.py:

```py
import unittest
import database as database
import os


class test_database(unittest.TestCase):

    def tearDown(self):
        os.remove('geminon.db')

    def test_create_tables(self):
        database.create_tables()
        database.cur.execute("insert into ships (name) values (?)", ('test_ship',))
        database.cur.execute("SELECT * FROM ships ", )
        self.assertIsNotNone(database.cur.fetchall())


class test_database_ships_functions(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        database.create_tables()

    def tearDown(self):
        os.remove('geminon.db')

    def test_add_ship(self):
        database.add_ship('test_ship1')
        database.db.commit()
        database.cur.execute("SELECT * FROM ships WHERE name=:name LIMIT 1", {'name': 'test_ship1'})
        self.assertIsNotNone(database.cur.fetchall())
```

When I run pytest, I get the following error:

```
self = <test_database.test_database_ships_functions testMethod=test_add_ship>

    def setUp(self):
>       database.create_tables()

test_database.py:21: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

    def create_tables():
        """
        create tables
        """
    
>       cur.execute("""
        CREATE TABLE ships (
        name                TEXT    PRIMARY KEY,
        classification      INTEGER DEFAULT   0,
        number              INTEGER DEFAULT   0,
        damage              INTEGER DEFAULT   0
        )
        """)
E       sqlite3.OperationalError: table ships already exists

database.py:12: OperationalError
```

Shouldn't the tearDown method in the `test_database` class destroy the database before `test_add_ships` runs? I must be misunderstanding how this is applied, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: You create a connection to the database, but that connection doesn't necessarily know that you've removed the *file* it connected to. You should explicitly drop the tables you create, instead of simply removing the backing file out from under the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be that `geminon.db` already exists before you start the tests.

It can also be connected to the fact that both tests share a global database.

Here is how I would go about doing this:

`database.py`

```py
import os
import sqlite3


class ShipDatabase:

    def __init__(self, db_name="geminon.db", fresh_db=False):
        self.db_name = db_name
        if fresh_db and os.path.exists(self.db_name):
            os.remove(self.db_name)
        self.con = sqlite3.connect(self.db_name, check_same_thread=False)

    def create_tables(self):
        cur = self.con.cursor()
        create_query = """
            CREATE TABLE ships (
                name                TEXT    PRIMARY KEY,
                classification      INTEGER DEFAULT   0,
                number              INTEGER DEFAULT   0,
                damage              INTEGER DEFAULT   0
            )
        """
        cur.execute(create_query)
        cur.close()

    def destroy_db(self):
        self.con.close()
        if os.path.exists(self.db_name):
            os.remove(self.db_name)

    def add_ship(self, name):
        cur = self.con.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM ships WHERE name=:name LIMIT 1", {'name': name})
        ship_does_not_exist = cur.fetchone() is None
        if ship_does_not_exist:
            cur.execute("insert into ships (name) values (?)", (name,))
            self.con.commit()
        cur.close()
        return ship_does_not_exist
```

`database_test.py`

```py
import unittest
from database import ShipDatabase


class TestDatabase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.sdb = ShipDatabase(fresh_db=True)
        self.sdb.create_tables()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.sdb.destroy_db()

    def test_create_tables(self):
        cur = self.sdb.con.cursor()
        cur.execute("insert into ships (name) values (?)", ('test_ship',))
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM ships ", )
        self.assertIsNotNone(cur.fetchall())
        cur.close()


class TestDatabaseShipsFunctions(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.sdb = ShipDatabase(fresh_db=True)
        self.sdb.create_tables()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.sdb.destroy_db()

    def test_add_ship(self):
        self.sdb.add_ship('test_ship1')
        cur = self.sdb.con.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM ships WHERE name=:name LIMIT 1", {'name': 'test_ship1'})
        self.assertIsNotNone(cur.fetchall())
        cur.close()
```

This implementation is missing exception handling.